# How to move div to the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put my `2nd div on the right side of the page`.

So apparently the 2nd div should be on the right side of the 1st div . At the moment is right under the 1st div and i want to put it on the right side of the first div and should remain responsive

I am trying to put my `2nd div on the right side of the page`.

So apparently the 2nd div should be on the right side of the 1st div . At the moment is right under the 1st div and i want to put it on the right side of the first div and should remain responsive

How can i get this done with css.

```
 <div class="container col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
        <div class="well well bs-component">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

       <--1st div -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Phone</label>    
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="typeahead  form-control" id="phone" placeholder=" Customer Phone Number" name="phone" required>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder=" Customer Name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        </div>
        <--End of 1st div -->


       <--2nd div -->
        <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel_1">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
     <tr> 
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     </table>                                                                                                                                                          
        </div>
        </div>
       <--End of 2nd div -->



       <--3rd div -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">

                  <div  class="nav-tabs-custom" id="tabs">

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    @foreach($countries as $country)

                       <li><a href="#tab_{{ $country->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$category->name!!}</a></li>
                       @endforeach


                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                    @foreach($countries as $key => $country)

                      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $country->id }}">
                      <table class="table" id="tables">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr> 
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th colspan="5"></th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody id="food_list">
                      @foreach($country->teams as $team)
                                         <tr>
                                            </tr>
                      @endforeach       
                   </tbody>
                   </table>
                     </div>
                    @endforeach     
                      </div>    

                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>
       <--End of 3rd div -->


        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: first div, second div, bla bla, bro i suggest you to make you question understandable by posting some screenshots or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div class="container col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
    <div class="well well bs-component">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

   <!--1st div --><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Phone</label>    
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" class="typeahead  form-control" id="phone" placeholder=" Customer Phone Number" name="phone" required>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 control-label"> Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder=" Customer Name" name="name" required>
    </div>
     </div></div>
    <!--End of 1st div -->


   <!--2nd div --><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel_1">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
 <tr> 
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Country</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>                                                                                                                                                          
    </div>
     </div></div>
   <!--End of 2nd div -->



   <!--3rd div -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">

              <div  class="nav-tabs-custom" id="tabs">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                @foreach($countries as $country)

                   <li><a href="#tab_{{ $country->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$category->name!!}</a></li>
                   @endforeach


                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                @foreach($countries as $key => $country)

                  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $country->id }}">
                  <table class="table" id="tables">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr> 
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th colspan="5"></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                   </thead>
                                   <tbody id="food_list">
                  @foreach($country->teams as $team)
                                     <tr>
                                        </tr>
                  @endforeach       
               </tbody>
               </table>
                 </div>
                @endforeach     
                  </div>    

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
   <!--End of 3rd div -->
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: it is not very responsive when the screen is smaller although it looks when screen is big

Comment: I would suggest you put the second div beneath the first div on very small screens, otherwise the text would be squished.

Comment: how do i achieve that? i am new to frontend design

Answer (score 0):

Few changes that you have to make:

- You have used col-md in some rows while for others you have used col-lg..? Either give each of your columns all size support by mentioning `col-lg, col-md, col-sm` like I have changed below.
- The columns which you need on the same row need to be wrapped inside one `class="row"` in bootstrap. That's why I have made `two columns with size col-8 and col-4` for your first and second div and wrapped them in row `instead of the forms`.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container col-lg-12  col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-offset-0 col-offset-0">
 <div class="well well bs-component">
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
   <!--1st div -->
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-8">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 control-label">Phone</label>
    <div class="">
     <input type="text" class="typeahead  form-control" id="phone" placeholder=" Customer Phone Number" name="phone" required>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-1 control-label"> Name</label>
    <div class="">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder=" Customer Name" name="name" required>
    </div>
   </div>
      </div>
   <!--End of 1st div -->
   <!--2nd div -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
   <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel_1">
     <table class="table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   <!--End of 2nd div -->
   <!--3rd div -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9 col-9">
     <div class="nav-tabs-custom" id="tabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       @foreach($countries as $country)
       <li><a href="#tab_{{ $country->id }}" data-toggle="tab">{!!$category->name!!}</a></li>
       @endforeach
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
       @foreach($countries as $key => $country)
       <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $country->id }}">
        <table class="table" id="tables">
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th colspan="5"></th>
           <th></th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="food_list">
          @foreach($country->teams as $team)
          <tr>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
       @endforeach
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!--End of 3rd div -->
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```